# Associate email addresses for my android application

Tags: java, android, email

I am an absolute beginner in android development. I am making a small email application. What I want to do is: when I click on any email in web browser, My application should be used to open this email. Now My phone shows only gmail, Drive, and Email only. How can I add my application too to the list.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use intent-filters.

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO" />
    <data  android:scheme="mailto" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category   android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
</intent-filter>
```

https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_email/blob/master/AndroidManifest.xml